# How to add default Calendar programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, calendar

How to add the default functionality of calendar control in my application?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand, which control are you talking about? What do you mean by "reach to calendar"?

Comment: u cannot show the default ios Calender in your app, but you can create and read events of the calendar using the EventKit framework, have look at this [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_iOS_6_Event_Kit_to_Create_Date_and_Location_Based_Reminders) for more information

Comment: In my application i want to use the calendar control for adding events to it,so i have already add the calender to it. But i want to add the events on selected date as like we add the events to default calendar of iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to duplicate the iOS calendar style using some of the open source components below:

[Kal -it is very good and detailed, exactly like iOS calendar](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)


[Tapku - very big but nice](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)


[CK Calendar- only month, without EventKit integraion.](https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar)


[For Day and Week View.](http://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui?)
[Also this.](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/maweekview)


[AB Calendar Picker - It is awesome with year control.](https://github.com/k06a/ABCalendarPicker)

It is better to see how all of this is implemented and then do something on your own.

Comment: Please check this do you have any idea about this.

Comment: @ios7 idea about what?

Comment: I mean the solution. Do you have any idea about it's solution, how this can be achieved.

Comment: @ios7 Yes I used Kal for month and day view. Week view I did some change and made it work.

Comment: CAn you guide here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168027/how-to-create-a-calendar-like-this/17173457?noredirect=1#17173457

Comment: @ios7 I have answered your question, lets continue there.