# iPAD calendar Control with month, day and week

Tags: ios, ipad, calendar

I've checked Google for enough time to get some good iPAD calendar control (UI) same as Native calendar app for iPAD.

I've got few options for example. 
Tapku calendar http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers It is basically for iPhone and does not show Week, month, Day view.
I've used KAL in one of my app. But again it is for iPhone and no Month, week, day view. 
muhku is good and close to what i want.But it does not show month view. https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui?

I know EventKit but it does not give you control to show actual calendar (As far as i know)

Can somebody please suggest me if there is control or library exist . It should show Month, Week, Day view and for iPAD.

OR if not than any suggestion would highly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see  [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060301/how-to-add-default-calendar-programatically-in-iphone-sdk/16061467#16061467)  that lists out all calendar controls available as open source. Upto my knowledge I dont think there is any component that handles all day,week and month in a single control, you gotta merge any two.

Comment: Thanks mate. I have already check muhku calendar. It is close to what i want. But i does not show month view. How can i use it to use month view?

Comment: You can take month calendar from CKCalendarView.

Comment: There is list also in Native calendar. If you know any suggestion?

Comment: I guess you can use Kal for Month View and for day, Week use MADayWeek View. All of them pull events from the EventKitStore so all data is going to be unique only thing being you will be using two set of controls to complete your purpose.

Comment: Will try that and if it works will accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try Apple's [Event Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EventKitUIFrameworkRef/_index.html) framework this has includes lots of ways to show and deal with times and dates in views such as calendar views.
Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a really good chapter(chapter 29) in [iOS 5 By Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-5-by-tutorials) that shows you how to work with calender APIs.

Comment: Yes you have to buy the book its $44 for the PDF version but it is a great resource for future projects